The mouse keeps moving by itself when I'm using a macro program in RDP sessions
my case is the following:
I have 10 VPS RDP sessions open on my computer at the same time. On each VPS I am running a Macro Recorder program (an autoclicker) that performs automated activities.
This software controls the mouse. The problem that is occurring is that the mouse movement of one Remote Session is interfering with the mouse movement of the other remote sessions.
So the mouse keeps moving from one remote session to another and clicking in the wrong places.
I would like to know if there is any way to isolate the mouse from a remote session so as not to interfere with the other remote session.
In the first few hours that I activate remote sessions, this does not happen.
This issue starts to occur after a few hours that the remote sessions are open and the autoclicker software is active.

It sounds like an issue that could be specific to your combination of operating system(s), rdp client, and autoclicker software. Can you add that information to your question? It would be weird for a remote rdp session to be able to affect the local one and other sessions
